Why is my code giving error "sklearn not defined" when i have imported the library?
My code:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pickle as pk
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn.utils import shuffle

data = pd.read_csv("student-mat.csv", sep=";")
data = data[["G1", "G2", "G3", "studytime", "failures", "absences"]]
print(data.head())
predict = "G3"
x = np.array(data.drop(predict, axis=1))
y = np.array(data[predict])
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.1)

When I run this code, it throws an error name sklearn is not defined. However, this is odd because I imported the right sklearn libraries.
The complete error:
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 14
     12 x = np.array(data.drop(predict, axis=1))
     13 y = np.array(data[predict])
---> 14 x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.1)
     15 linear = linear_model.LinearRegression()
     16 linear.fit(x_train, y_train)

NameError: name 'sklearn' is not defined


from sklearn import linear_model
You only imported the linear_model function from sklearn, not the whole library. You can either also add model_selection to the import and call it without the sklearn. or just add another line of import sklearn

NameError always means that the Python interpreter does not know the thing you're using — in this case, it was not imported. You need to add import sklearn to your imports if you want to use it that way.
Most people do not import all of sklearn, however. But instead do this:
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

Then:
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.1)

This can help keep your code more compact and readable.
(Most people would also do from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression then use LinearRegression directly. Also note that later on you will find that if you import pickle as pk, then you will need to do pk.dump(), because you gave the alias pk to the library.)
